# Disable graph_total in Munin Graphs

Tags: munin, graph

Is there any way to *disable* the `graph_total` for a Munin graph? For example, the `apache_processes` plugin generates a "total" line that becomes meaningless when there are multiple ports monitored. I'd like the "total" line to not be graphed. I've tried:

```
apache_processes.graph_total ""
apache_processes.graph_total 0
apache_processes.graph_total
```

in my `/etc/munin/munin.conf` (below the host definition) to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

On your munin node you need to find apache_processes file (on our centos installations it is located in /usr/share/munin/plugins/apache_processes ) and comment this line:

```
print "graph_total total\n";
```